# Unity 2D: Character splits apart on game mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, character

I am trying to create a game and I followed some tutorials on Youtube (mostly Brackeys) on how to build a character and adjust his movements and animations.
My character works fine except one thing: whenever I begin game mode, the characters split apart. (Added pictures)
Can anyone tell me why is it happening?
Thank you :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: screenshot your scene hierarchy please, are the transforms connected?

Comment: I added a screen picture. All the character parts are under the character object. Is that what you mean by connected?

Comment: That looks fine. this way the child objects (leg, arms etc) should move with the parent object (marshmellow) Do all parts have a rigidbody?

Comment: make sure you uncheck any 'freeze positions' on the rigidbodies of your character's parts.

Comment: The parts are moving simultaneously but not connected as a body. The body parts did not have rigidbody. I added it but it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After a lot of prying I discovered that for some reason my animations freaked out after rearranging my body parts when on later stages of preparing the character. Because of that when I got into the Idle animation, the character got split up.